# Python Wildcard Entry Search for Windows Services

Tags: python, service, window

I am working on a project to build a tool using python to search for Windows services starting with specific string, say ABC*. This has to run on multiple server and stop or start service as per user input.

Before stop I also want to store the current status.

Something like below function of Powershell. Please suggest. 
**Example 4: Get services that begin with a search string and an exclusion
PowerShell
Copy
Get-Service -Name "win*" -Exclude "WinRM"**

Regards, 
Girwar

Answer (score 0):

Install the psutil package: pip install psutil

```
import psutil

services = [x for x in psutil.win_service_iter() if x.name().lower().startswith('win') and not x.name() == 'WinRM']

for service in services:
    svc = psutil.win_service_get(service.name())
    print('{} = {}'.format(svc.name(), svc.status())
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I can get this worked on local machine. My objective is to run it on remote machines. Any library to use with psutil to connect with remote machines. Sorry for dumb query but this is my first learning project i...

Comment: The easiest way I can think of to do what you are looking for is to use Powershell and enable Remote Powershell on the machines you want to work with.  That doesn't fit well with your learning goal but you'll get things working quickly.

Comment: thank you for sharing. I managed to get this done using Powershell only.